# three.js python converter error

Tags: python, three.js

am converting my .obj model into three.js json with the use of python converter given in the three.js, i have installed python and i can run the simple python program, if i try to convert my .obj to .js am getting following error

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\3d-viewer\documents\mrdoob-three.js-d3cb4e7\utils\converters\obj
>convert_obj_three.py -i male02.obj -o male02.js
Converting [male02.obj] into [male02.js] ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\3d-viewer\documents\mrdoob-three.js-d3cb4e7\utils\conver
ters\obj\convert_obj_three.py", line 1581, in <module>
    convert_ascii(infile, morphfiles, colorfiles, outfile)
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\3d-viewer\documents\mrdoob-three.js-d3cb4e7\utils\conver
ters\obj\convert_obj_three.py", line 1106, in convert_ascii
    "faces"     : ",".join(generate_face(f, fc) for f, fc in zip(faces, colorFac
es)),
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\3d-viewer\documents\mrdoob-three.js-d3cb4e7\utils\conver
ters\obj\convert_obj_three.py", line 1106, in <genexpr>
    "faces"     : ",".join(generate_face(f, fc) for f, fc in zip(faces, colorFac
es)),
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\3d-viewer\documents\mrdoob-three.js-d3cb4e7\utils\conver
ters\obj\convert_obj_three.py", line 665, in generate_face
    for i in xrange(nVertices):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`xrange` is a Python2 function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) which has been [removed from Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). The error

```
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

suggests you have installed Python3 while `convert_obj_three.py` requires Python2.

Comment: found it replaced range() instead of `xrange` it worked

Comment: I'm very glad for you! Not all Python2 programs can be converted to Python3 so easily.